# Software tools for recording non-reproducible bugs

Tags: debugging, bug-tracking

Obviously the non-reproducible bugs are the hardest to fix due to the nature of their cause (i.e. race conditions), so we as programmers must do our best to gather data (i.e. logs, screenshots, etc.) and verify the bug documentation is accurate in an attempt to understand what happened.  Can anyone recommend any software tools, or methods,  that can record and reconstitute the actual executed sequence of machine instructions while allowing the user to step through them and inspect the code?

If it helps, the project I'm building is a windows application written in C++ and uses VS2005.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [“Works on my machine” - How to fix non-reproducible bugs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102716/works-on-my-machine-how-to-fix-non-reproducible-bugs)

Comment: The "Works on my machine" thread discusses techniques to fixing non-reproducible bugs. This question is very specific and different in that it's asking about bug recording software (not profiling software).

Answer (score 1):

'Time-machine' / Replay debugging is very helpful for debugging the type of issues you describe.

eg [Green Hills time machine debugger](http://www.ghs.com/products/timemachine.html)

I have not used this myself but it sounds like it might be useful for the type of project you are building: [VMWare replay debugging](http://www.replaydebugging.com/2008/08/getting-started-with-replay-debugging.html)

Comment: A more general name for this kind of debugger is [omniscient debugger](http://pleiad.dcc.uchile.cl/tod/) or [reversible debugger](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/debugger.html), there are several others out there.